# returning multiple queries with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, promise

I've tried encapsulating two query responses on an object, and then using the object on the function return

```
app.get('/gerais',(req,res) => {
    const client = new Client();
    const data = new Object();
    client.connect()
        .then(() => {
            data.result1 = client.query('SELECT * FROM student');
            data.result2 = client.query('SELECT * FROM adress');

            return data;
        })
        .then((results) => {
            console.log('results?',results);
            res.render('geral-info',results);
        });
});
```

but 'results' in terminal prints:

```
results? { result1: Promise { <pending> }, result2: Promise { <pending> } }
```

How can I adjust so that this 'pending' can be filled with the actual string that is returned in each query?

Comment: You need to *resolve* the promises, e.g. using `Promise.all`. I'd strongly recommend reading tutorials on the basic use of promises before trying to use libraries with that as an API, or you won't get very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.query()` returns a promise, not the results of the query.  So, you need to know when that promise resolves so you can then get the data out of the promise.

If you have two promises (which you do) and you want to know when they are both done, you can use `Promise.all()`.  That will return a new promise that resolves to an array of results when both the other promises resolve:

```
client.connect()
    .then(() => {
        return Promise.all([client.query('SELECT * FROM student'), client.query('SELECT * FROM adress')])
    })
    .then((results) => {
        console.log('results?',results);
        // res.render('geral-info',{something from the results});
    });
```

Comment: it looks good, but the `results[].data` returns values like `rows: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]],` and not the results of query response

Comment: @MutanAsul - Well, I'm just getting you the results from the query (what the query operation returns).  If you want some specific item out of each query, then you need to show me what that data looks like and tell me what you want out of it.

Comment: In terminal, `console.log('results?',results);` should return an object with the result of the query.
before it was like this: `results? {result1: Promise {<pending>}, result2: Promise {<pending>}}`.
Now, with your recommendation to solve Promise, I have, e.g ,`results?{rows: [ [Object], [Object]]}`, while I need something like `results?{rows: [ {name:student1,other cloumns..}, {name:student2,..}]}`.
After the promise was resolved, would have something equivalent to a stringfy () so that it would return the query response string instead of this "Object" ?

I was clear?

Comment: `{rows: [ [Object], [Object]]}` is `{rows: [ {name:student1,other cloumns..}, {name:student2,..}]}`  Same thing.  You just have to look at the details of those objects.  I don't know what console environment you're using that isn't showing you the internals of the objects, but you need to look inside the objects to see the actual data.  If you really have to, you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(results))`.

Comment: you are right, I think it ends up mixing more with other technologies that I am wanting to use same, my terminal is VSCode, I do not know if you know it, but I use mustache, which reads a terminal session, eg:` rows: [[Object ], [Object]],` and then I render the mustache with the contents of that vector, my difficulty being that it appeared as 'Object'.
But now I think that question would fit into a new topic.
Thanks for the help and the attention.